# What's the equivalent ssh config of this ssh tunnel command?

Tags: ssh-tunneling, ssh-config

I have a `host2` remotely forwarding its ssh connection to port 2222 on `host1`. I am using the following command on `host0` to connect to `host2` via `host1`.

```
ssh -tt host1 ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

Is there an equivalent ssh config for this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Host host2
    ProxyJump host1
    Port 2222
    HostName localhost
```

If not, then this

```
 Host host2
    ProxyCommand ssh host1 nc localhost 2222
```